# Win32 Subclassed Window Messages

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

I have a Static Window with a Button Window inside in a Win32 application, and I subclassed the button so I get to handle it's messages with my single "MessageProc".

```
void MyProgram::Initialize(WNDPROC messageProc)
{
    //Here I create a bunch of windows
    _resourceWindow = CreateWindow("STATIC", "Resources", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SIZEBOX, 5, 5, 200, 600, 0, 0, _mainInstance, NULL);
    //The child button
    _resourceAddButton = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Add", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 5, 20, 50, 20, _resourceWindow, 0, _mainInstance, NULL);

    _resourceAddButtonWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(_resourceAddButton, GWLP_WNDPROC, (WNDPROC)messageProc);
    //Messages from this button are sent to messageProc now
}

void MyProgram::SubclassesProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            if(hWnd == _resourceAddButton) //I have more than one child button so I'll have to do this one by one right?
            {
                CallWindowProc(_resourceAddButtonWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This "SubclassesProc" is called in the default part of my "messageProc" function.

The way it is now, my Button isn't getting the "clicks" at all, I click but nothing happens (it doesn't change visually and doesn't call WM_COMMAND either).
I'm guessing that it's because now all messages from that Button is being handled by the messageProc function, and this is causing some message blocking... for example the WM_LBUTTONDOWN in the Button control never gets called because I already have a:

```
switch(uMsg)
{
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        //I'm doing something else
        break;
    }
    //bunch of other commands
    default:
    {
        myProgram.SubclassesProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
}
```

So SubclassesProc with WM_LBUTTONDOWN never gets called, and the Button can't be clicked and it won't proc WM_COMMAND because of this.

What's the proper way to handle this?

For now I'm considering rewriting the messageProc function but I'd have to take in consideration every subclassed window in nearly every user input message there is... or just forget about subclassing.

Comment: When you subclass a window then you *must* pass all messages that you don't specifically handle yourself to the original window procedure.  Which is what is missing in your code.

Comment: I tried adding a CallWindowProc to the original Button messageProc in my Subclasses function, but it never gets called because the main messageProc gets precedence, and after it deals with WM_LBUTTONDOWN, it breaks out of the loop and the Subclasses never gets called.
Most examples/tutorials show this working with a single subclassed window, so they just use the originalProc in their default statement and it works. So I'm guessing subclassing isn't meant to be used with a bunch of grandchildren windows, right?

Comment: You can sub-class anything you like, you just have to do it right. Your SubclassesProc function is only passing WM_PAINT through, it needs to pass everything through.